# how to resolve this error about RHCSA certification varification

Tags: operating-system, redhat

I try to verify RHCSA certificate but the sources give me message like

> The user associated with this Certification ID has not mapped his or
>   her ID to a redhat.com login. If this is your Certification ID error

Comment: Wrong site. You're looking for [su] instead. This site is for programming related questions.

Answer (score 2):

The rest of the error message you're quoting provides a [link to a page](http://www.europe.redhat.com/training/verify-addl-info/) that explains the problem in more detail:

> Red Hat Certified Professionals (RHCP) must associate their certification ID with a redhat.com login in order for their certification to be validated on the Verify page or to be found in a search.

The page also provides instructions on how to do just that:

> 1. Go to [www.redhat.com](http://www.redhat.com/) and click the "person" icon in the upper right-hand corner (it is the one in the middle.)
> 2. If you already have a personal account, log into that account.  If you do not have an account, or if you usually use a corporate account used by multiple people, please create a new account by registering with Red Hat.  Once you have created the account, log in.
> 3. Click on **Certifications**.
> 4. Click on **Add Certifications** on menu from left under **Your Certifications**.
> 5. Provide your certification ID in the text field and **Submit**.

Comment: yes that certificate need to register thank you.